# How differentiable programming and programming language supporting it will potentially help the development towards AGI?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, agi, research, programming-languages

After the state of the art Deep Learning techniques/algorithms being implemented in low-level languages like Objective-C, C++, etc to high-level languages like Python, JS, etc. and with the help of huge libraries like [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/), [Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/), [Scikit-Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/), etc.

Now, [Swift](https://swift.org/): Google's bet on [differentiable programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_programming), they are making Swift differential programming ready see [this manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/DifferentiableProgramming.md) and they are building TensorFlow from the ground up in swift [S4TF](https://www.tensorflow.org/swift).

So, how *differentiable programming* and programming language supporting it will *potentially* help the development towards AGI?